# How to find perimeter between Tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

So I have to write a function where tuples are given, and you have to calculate the distance between them and add them all together. I don't know how tuples work so please help. Here is what I have so far

```
import math
#Permimeter
def perimeter(x1,x2,y1,y2):
  dist = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
  return dist
```

It doesn't work, saying unsupported operand type for tuples. I don't know how to make sure it still works if you have more or less inputs 
Here's a test case of what it should do

```
tri = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))
>>> perimeter(tri)
3.414213562373095
```

Comment: Tuples work just like lists with indexing, if you have tuple=(‘a’,’b’,’c’), tuple[0] will be ‘a’ and tuple[2] will be ‘c’.

Comment: `tri` has 3 tuples and function definition is expecting 4 variables. So, what should be x1, x2, y1, y2 in your example?

Comment: well that's the examples from the assignment and what it should be done, I didn't know how to use tuples

Comment: Give a valid example, your formula in code is for `distance between 2 points`, but your `tri` variable has 3 tuples, which represents 3 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the problem down into segments.  Hopefully nobody here gives you a complete answer, because it looks like H/W.  But you will get tips on incorrect code.

As stated, your "perimeter" function is calculating the distance between 2 points that are passed in as values for x1, x2, y1, y2.  That function cannot take tuples as inputs.  So you have a couple things to do:

1. Figure out how to use this function to calculate the length of **all** of the sides of your triangle.  (Perhaps a loop or directly plugging & chugging)
2. figure out how to match the inputs (signature) of the function with what you have

If you know how to index into lists, you can do it for tuples same way.  one way:

```
In [13]: tri = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))                                         

In [14]: tri[0]                                                                 
Out[14]: (0, 0)

In [15]: tri[0][0]                                                              
Out[15]: 0

In [16]: x1 = tri[0][0]  # etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is you're trying to pass a tuple instead of 4 variables to a function

What the function is essentially doing is getting the distance between two points. To get the perimeter you will need to add the distances between all the points. Since its a triangle, you will need to add the length of 3 sides.
One way would be to iterate through all the points and add them to a variable. the best way would be to use a generator and take the sum. 
The solution code would be:

```
import math
#Perimeter
def perimeter(x1,x2,y1,y2):
  dist = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
  return dist
tri = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))
peri = sum(perimeter(tri[i][0], tri[i-1][0], tri[i][1], tri[i-1][1]) for i in range(len(tri)))
print(peri)
```

perimeter is essentially cycling through the entire list, two at a time, the last and first, first and second , second and third and passing them through the function. Its then adding all the values to get the total perimeter

if you want to do the entire thing with one function try:

```
import math
def perimeter(tri):
  return sum(math.sqrt((tri[i][0]-tri[i-1][0])**2, (tri[i][1]-tri[i-1][1])**2) for i in range(len(tri)))
tri = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))
print(perimeter(tri)
```

Comment: seems nice but you should have `range(1, len(tri))`

Comment: @ValentinVIGNAL The reason for starting from the default is 0 so it takes the last value. That way all the points are considered. Otherwise only 2 sides would come

Answer (score 0):

You may like this solution, the only condition is that touples should be in the right order:

```
tri = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))

def perimeter(corners):
    dist = 0
    i = 0
    for corner in corners:
        print(corner)
        if(i != len(corner)):
            dist += math.sqrt((corners[i][0]-corners[i+1][0])**2 + (corners[i][1]-corners[i+1][1])**2)
        else:
            dist += math.sqrt((corners[0][0]-corners[i][0])**2 + (corners[0][1]-corners[i][1])**2)
        i+=1
    return dist

print(perimeter(tri))
```

Comment: It says int object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

you can get x1 y1 x2 y2 or just points:

```
    import math


    def distance(point1, point2):
        x1 = point1[0]
        y1 = point1[1]
        x2 = point2[0]
        y2 = point2[1]
        return math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)


    print(distance((1, 2), (3, 4)))
```

you will get:

```
    C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe 
    2.8284271247461903

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do:

```
tri = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1))
perimeter(tri)
```

It is equivalent to

```
perimeter(((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)))
```

So you put a tuple of 3 tuples as parameter of `perimeter`. Each tuple represent coordinates of each points of your figure.

Then, you have two things to do:

1. Calculate each distance between each points
2. Add them to get the perimeter

Each step should be a function.

You have a start for the step 1 but you get an error. For the distance you need coordinates of two points, so you need 2 tuples p1 and p2 which have two coordinates:

To access each coordinates you must use `p1[0]` which is the x-value of the point p1 and `p1[1]` which is its y-value.

For the second step, just create an other function taking `tri` as parameter. In this function you just need to add the results of three calls of function1(p1, p2). You just need to figure out with a for loop how you can do :

```py
# This is a general exemple  
# with
tri = ((a1,a2), (b1,b2), (c1,c2), (d1,d2))

#In the for loop of function2 you should call
function2(a,b)
function2(b,c)
function2(c,d)
function2(d,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is confusing because tuples would be used at two levels. First to represent a point as a pair of x and y values. Second to collect a number of points into a triangle. It is also confusing because the perimeter function above looks like it should be called distance. Codewise, you can start by renaming the perimeter function distance and modifying its arguments to take (x,y) tuples. Without giving it all away, you'd have a function distance(a,b) where a and b are tuples. You could call it like:

```
distance((0,1),(0,))
```

Read that call to mean finding the distance between two points (0,1) and (0,0). Inside that function, you'd use the square brackets to get to the x part or y part of a point.

```
def distance(a,b):      
    a_x = a[0]
    a_y = a[1] 
    # more details omitted
```

Then write a new perimeter function to take a tuple of points (themselves tuples) and calculate the perimeter, as shown in the second code snippet. The call to distance would look like:

```
a=(0,0)
b=(0,1) 
d=distance(a,b)
```